# Material-ui: Difference between Expansion Panels and Collapse

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What is the main difference here? Why would you use one over the other?

I began using Collapse, but then noticed Expansion Panels exist as well, and it got me confused as to which one we should be using.

Answer (score 5):

The Collapse component doesn't display anything on its own, it describes a relationship between two other components that do. The Material UI docs explain that it is used to make the Vertical Stepper component.

The Expansion Panel is a complete package, it has the collapsing behavior, but also it provides the panels that are displayed as well. If you look at the [source code for ExpansionPanel](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanel/ExpansionPanel.js), you'll see that it uses `Collapse` in its render function.

I would say that if the Expansion Panel is good enough for you, use that. Otherwise, if you need to expand/collapse things that aren't panels, use the Collapse component.

Edit: See here for how to use Collapse and other transitions: https://material-ui.com/utils/transitions/

Comment: Thanks.

My question arose because I was building a collapse functionality for a <Card /> component. I had not seen Expansion Panels, so i just used a Collapse button on my <CardHeader />, and wrapped the <CardBody /> with <Collapse />

This works fine as far as i know.

Comment: Yeah, you probably have more flexibility with the route you chose

Comment: Thanks. This made me confused as well. While Collapse only exists in the Component API documentation, and Expansion Panel exists in Components documentation